# Creating a function in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I have a stored procedure that updates a couple aggregates and a function - by dropping them, the assembly and re-importing them.

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [maint].[UpdateSqlClr]
AS
     BEGIN

    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.[HistoricAnalysis]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[HistoricAnalysis];
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.[OverallStatus]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP AGGREGATE [dbo].[OverallStatus];
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.[OverallStatusBreakdown]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP AGGREGATE [dbo].[OverallStatusBreakdown];
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.assemblies
    WHERE [name] = 'SuperDbSqlCLR'
)
    DROP ASSEMBLY [SuperDbSqlCLR];

CREATE ASSEMBLY [SuperDbSqlCLR] FROM 'd:\Super\SuperDb.Sql.CLR\SuperDb.SqlClr.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;


CREATE AGGREGATE [dbo].[OverallStatus]
(@input [NVARCHAR](4000)
)
RETURNS [NVARCHAR](4000)
EXTERNAL NAME
     SuperDbSqlCLR.[SuperDb.SqlClr.OverallStatus];
CREATE AGGREGATE [dbo].[OverallStatusBreakdown]
(@input [NVARCHAR](4000)
)
RETURNS [NVARCHAR](4000)
EXTERNAL NAME
     [SuperDbSqlCLR].[SuperDb.SqlClr.OverallStatusBreakdown];

-- Where the GO would be in a query window

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[HistoricAnalysis] ()
RETURNS TABLE (
  [Sequence] [int] NULL,
  [Text] [nvarchar](100) NULL
)
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [SuperDbSqlCLR].[SuperDb.SqlClr.UserDefinedFunctions].[HistoricAnalysis]

    END
```

The problem is that while I can add a GO when just running the contents of the SPROC in a query window, SPROC creations don't seem to like the GO statement, and every time, I get a syntax error that 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the only statement in the batch --

Is there anyway to do this in a SPROC?

Comment: This is a copout, but: have you tried it in dynamic sql?

Comment: It's not a copout... Dynamic SQL is the **ONLY** way you can create a function from within a stored procedure.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson: it's not a copout - it's the standard way of doing this sort of thing. In my opinion, it's a weird thing to do. But I support alternative lifestyles.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson you should add that as an answer -- worked here -- :-)

Comment: +1 to all of the above. I said it was a copout because I try to avoid dynamic sql whenever possible :) But as you guys point out, it is the right solution in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work using the [exec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql#using-execute-with-a-character-string) command, i.e. dynamic SQL.